# Showing unauthorized while deleting item.a

Tags: angular

I wan to delete some user from Admin but when I am trying to delete it is showing unauthorized, I do not know why ? 
Here is the my a:

```
manageUser = function (obj, _id, email, type) {
    debugger;
    if (type == "add") {
//   return this.http.post(this.api_url + "category/add", JSON.stringify(), this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
 }
  else if (type == "update") {
         return this.http.post(this.api_url + "admin/changeuseremail/" + _id, JSON.stringify(email), this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
 }
     {
        return this.http.post(this.api_url + "admin/delete-user/" + obj._id,  this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

userlist.ts code goes here to set delete value

```
// Delete Selected Category
deleteSelectedUser = function (user) {
    debugger;
    this.isActivatedAdd = false;
    this.isActivatedEdit = false;
    this.isActivatedDelete = true;
    this.modalTitle = "Delete User";
    this.btnTitle = "Yes";
    this.selectedUserId = user._id;
    this.user = user
   //this.selectedUser = user;
    this.selected_name = user.name;
    // this.selecteddob = user.selected_dob;
    // this.selectedGender = user.gender;
    // this.selectedDistance = user.distance;
    // this.selecteAgerange = user.agerange;
    // this.selectedstatus = user.status;
}
```

to delete user code goes here :

```
// manage new category
manageUser = function (userForm,) {
    debugger;
    if (this.userForm.valid && this.isActivatedAdd) {
        this.btnTitle = "Saving...";
        jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        this.authService.manageUser(userForm, "add").subscribe(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                jQuery.growl.notice({ title: 'Success', message: data.message });
                this.getUserList(1, this.limit);
            }
            else {
                jQuery.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: data.error });
            }
            jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
            this.authService.cancelProcess();
        });
    }
    else if (this.userForm.valid && this.isActivatedEdit) {
        userForm._id = this.selectedUserId;
        this.btnTitle = "Updating...";
        jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        this.authService.manageUser(this.userForm, this.selectedUserId, "update").subscribe(data => {
            if (data.success) {
                this.getUserList(this.pageNo, this.limit);
                jQuery.growl.notice({ title: 'Success', message: data.message });
            }
            else {
                jQuery.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: data.error });
            }
            jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
            this.authService.cancelProcess();
        });
    }
    else if (this.isActivatedDelete) {
        userForm._id = this.selectedUserId;
        this.btnTitle = "Deleting...";
        jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
        this.authService.manageUser( userForm, "delete").subscribe(data => {
            debugger;
            if (data.success) {
                this.getUserList(this.pageNo, this.limit, this.searchStr);
                jQuery.growl.notice({ title: 'Success', message: data.message });
            }
            else {
                jQuery.growl.error({ title: 'Error', message: data.message });
            }
            jQuery(':button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
            this.authService.cancelProcess();
        });
    }
    else {
        this.validationService.validateAllFormFields(this.userForm);
    }
}
```

the problems is when I am clicking on delete button it is showing me unauthorized error.

Your help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you pass auth token in the delete request, also the issue would be related to the Http request you are making from the angular app try to check your chrome network console and  check your request header  if you are making the request properly. or test the api with the post man to see if the api is working properly

Comment: also shouldn't you be using  `this.http.delete()`  instead of post `this.http.post()`     here ?

Comment: I checked it on Postman it working fine there but not here

Comment: I am using same header to get userlist but and getting proiperly but not here
` // Get user list
    userList = function (pageNo, limit, searchStr, time) {
        debugger;
        return this.http.get(this.api_url + 'admin/user-list/' + pageNo + "/" + limit + "?time=" + time + "&search=" + searchStr, this.getAuthHeaderOption()).map(res => res.json());
    }`

Comment: // Get auth header options//

  
 
  
`getAuthHeaderOption() {
          this.authToken = localStorage.getItem('admin_web_token');
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authToken);
        let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return option;
        
    }
`